# Syntastic + Django

Tags: django, syntax-checking, syntastic

I just started developing on Django, and then I thought using the [Syntastic syntax checker](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) on it would be a good idea.

The problem is that it complains about some things being wrong when, in fact, they aren't.

Examples:

1. For

   ```
   from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
   ```

   I get:

   ```
   error| [F0401] Unable to import 'django.core.urlresolvers'
   ```
2. For

   ```
   amount = self.sale_set.filter(date__year=year).aggregate(sum=Sum('amount'))["sum"]
   ```

   I get (where `self` is an `Album`)

   ```
   error| [E1101, Album.get_sales_total] Instance of 'Album' has no 'sale_set' member
   ```

This code runs perfectly even with these "errors", but how can I make Syntastic behave correctly?

Comment: This should be a bug report to the developers of Syntastic, then.

Comment: More likely a bug in flake8, pyflakes, or pylint as they're the default syntax checkers used by Syntastic.

Answer (score 5):

piggybacking on @supervacuo's answer:

there is a way to get this working for syntastic and it's rather straightforward, if not easy to figure out for someone unfamiliar with syntastic options (like, say, me):

in your .vimrc, add this line:

`let g:syntastic_python_pylint_args = "--load-plugins pylint_django"`

of course, this does require `pylint-django` be installed in your environment

Answer (score 4):

Both of these messages come from `pylint` — you can see fuller explanations with `pylint --help-msg=$ID`, or on http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/.

You can disable the checks with *e.g.* `from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
  # pylint: disable=F0401`, but that gets tiresome pretty quickly.

There's a [pylint plugin for Django](https://github.com/landscapeio/pylint-django) which will definitely fix your E1101 (and I hope the F0401 too). Maybe have a go at installing the plugin and configuring Syntastic to use it?

Comment: Nice suggestion, but did not work for me. At least, within a virtualenv.